# Пунктуация. Является ли данный пример прямой речью?

Tags: пунктуация

Я запутался. Нужны ли двоеточие и кавычки в данном примере:

*Ты ждёшь. Хочу сказать: "напрасно".*

Кто-то говорит, что всё верно, кто-то утверждает, что кавычки не нужны, третий человек говорит, что нужно убрать кавычки и заменить двоеточие на тире. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше использовать такое оформление: ***Ты ждёшь. Хочу сказать –  напрасно.***

1. Кавычки не нужны, это не прямая речь. Мы оформляем текст в виде бессоюзного сложного предложения (БСП) с **изъяснительным** значением.

Классический вариант таких отношений при постановке **двоеточия**, но здесь лучше использовать **тире,** что характерно для разноструктурных предложений небольшого объема.

2. **Интонация** эти знаков отличается тем, что при постановке тире **пауза короче**, а при использовании двоеточия нужно делать увеличенную предупредительную  паузу, что в данном случае не является необходимым. Двоеточие обычно ставится при большей **распространенности** второй части.
3. А когда применяется **прямая речь**? Для сравнения: *И тогда я сказал ей: «Ты ждешь меня напрасно».*

Здесь автор воспроизводит то, что было сказано им раньше, тогда такое оформление возможно.